# if 文で使われる != はどのような意味ですか？

Tags: python

単純な質問で、調べても分からなかったので教えていただきたいです。

```
if (sys.flags.interactive != 1)
```

上の if 文の `!= 1` はどのような意味になるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

C系(C・C++・C#・Java・PHP・Python等)の開発言語における関係演算子の一種で、「非等価演算子」すなわち「等しくない」を表す演算子になります。

Answer (score 2):

ノットイコールです。

自分もPythonに詳しい訳ではありませんが、多くのプログラミング言語でノットイコールを意味するのではないでしょうか。

[Pythonにおける!=（ノットイコール）の利用方法について現役エンジニアが解説【初心者向け】](https://techacademy.jp/magazine/44136)